# Got "Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" everytime I change my code unless I clear the cache in symfony 6 with Docker

Tags: docker, caching, symfony6, php-8.1

Everytime I reload the page, if have made changes in my code, I will get : Error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded.
A directory named Container... will appear in the path var/cache/dev . In order to make my application work again, I need to delete this Container directory and do a cache:clear.
My application worked just fine for months without this problem. I don't know what caused it.

I'm using Docker, Symfony 6 with PHP 8.1.

I don't want to increase my max_execution time, I want to fix this issue.
Does somebody know why I need to clear the cache everytime? It's weird. I found nobody else who has this issue.

Comment: if the real execution time is less then value of `max_execution_time` in `php.ini`, then it's a bug of macos version of php: https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12814